# How can I get the proper factorial numbers of the user inputs?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I want to get the factorial of each number correctly that the user inputted. The factorial of the first input is correct but the factorial of the next inputs are incorrect.

This is what I get: [the output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJT20.png)

The output/factorial should be like this: [correct factorial of numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02TEr.png)

Here is my code:

```
public class Factor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner type = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int i, fact = 1;
    System.out.println("<------ FACTORIAL CALCULATOR ------>");
    
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
        int num = type.nextInt();
        
        
        if (num > 0) {
            System.out.print(num + "! = ");
            
            for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
                System.out.print(i);
                
                if(i != num) {
                    System.out.print(" x ");    
                }
            }
            for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
                fact = fact * i;
            }
            System.out.println("\nThe factorial of " + num + " is: " + fact);
            
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid input! Program stopped!");
            break;
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The answer is quite simple, you are never resetting your `factorial` variable after succeeding once.

Simply move the `fact` variable declaration into your while loop and it will work.

Comment: This line sir // fact = fact * i //?

Comment: I get it sir, thank you so muchhhhh:>